# ¿Cómo manejar la respuesta de una carga útil personalizada en Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow

Tengo un robot que maneja bien el intento de bienvenida usando Dialogflow para Slack. Sin embargo, no sé cómo manejar la respuesta a la `intención de bienvenida` de disparar el segundo poste. De hecho, el `welcome intent`, que produce un contexto de `wait_answer1`, muestra la siguiente plantilla en json:

```
{
  "slack": {
    "text": "",
    "attachments": [
      {
        "blocks": [
          {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": "*How have you been feeling?* Poll by <fakeLink.toUser.com|Mihailo>"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "divider"
          },
          {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": ":tired_face: *I’ve been feeling more exasperated and hopeless*"
            },
            "accessory": {
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              },
              "value": "1"
            }
          },
          {
            "accessory": {
              "value": "2",
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              }
            },
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": ":expressionless: *Generally, less freaked out than other people*"
            }
          },
          {
            "accessory": {
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "emoji": true,
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Vote"
              },
              "value": "3"
            },
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": ":relieved: *More calm and hopeful*"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "divider"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Y me gustaría manejar la respuesta. Así que creé una intención de `answer1` que toma la `await_answer1` como un contexto de entrada. Las frases de entrenamiento son la salida de la plantilla anterior: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`. Y la respuesta del texto por defecto es `¡Interesante!` Sin embargo, después de seleccionar la respuesta es la `intención de retroceso` en lugar de la `answer1`. Por lo tanto, ¿cómo manejar la respuesta de un payload personalizado en dialogflow?

Answer (score 0):

lo estas haciendo de la forma correcta pero no te reconoce los contexto por que cuando el usuario preciona el boton en tu bot, slack envia un evento a DialogFlow y este crea una nueva sesion y en esta no esta el contexto, es como una conversacion nueva, por lo que borrando los contextos de tu bot funcionaria, creo que este comportamiento es debido a que en la Integración Dialogflow usan dos APIS una para los mensajes y otra para los eventos y si vemos la de los eventos es la versión 1 del API de dialogflow.